# Url Rewrite 2.0 with Asp.net 3.5 sp1

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, url, url-rewriting

After a my initial research about selecting a best option for httpredirects on my site. I decided to go ahead and install UrlRewrite 2.0 IIS7 extension. (I used this link to set up a rule ["Url Rewrite by Scott Gu"](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/20/tip-trick-fix-common-seo-problems-using-the-url-rewrite-extension.aspx)) Everything is fine with the setup, and after adding a rewrite rule I have this in my config file

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="AddCameraRule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="http://localhost/App1/addSomething/" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost/App2/addsomething.aspx" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

But I get 404 error when I try to access the url http://localhost/App1/addSomething. I figured out I might have to add a wildcard mapping in IIS7 (because this is an extensionless url) but I am still not sure about it (because it seems its already there with integrated pipeline n I have my apps in integrated pipeline), just gave it a try but it still didnt work. Can anyone see whats wrong with this.

Comment: Have you looked at Routing vs URL Rewriting, routing is arguably a better long term solution and far more flexible

Comment: yes. I am also using a routing in my site, but i am not sure if you can do a http redirect in a different application, because it cannot create an instance of other application. this is a redirect to a different application/site. I tried adding a route in app1 web.config like "addsomething" mapped to "~/app2/something.aspx" and I have a virtual directory pointing to app2 but it gives an error cannot instantiate app2. Do you know how to do this with routing?

Comment: Use a redirect.aspx page and pass in the parameters, this way you can be more flexible

Comment: can you please explain this in some more detail?

Comment: Create a page to receive redirected URL's <match url="http://localhost/App1/addSomething/" /> would be a routed to a page that would look for any QueryString or route Params, based on this the page could simply call Response.Redirect("http://localhost/App2/addsomething.aspx");

Comment: What happens when you try to navigate to `http://localhost/App1/addSomething/` (with the trailing slash)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved a problem using url routing itself by creating RedirectRouteHandler to redirect with 301 to a different website or application.
[used this link for help](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/12/15/redirect-routes-and-other-fun-with-routing-and-lambdas.aspx)